# Ubuntu 16.04, Nvidia and ACPI issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, acpi

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 in Legacy Mode on a MSI PE60 6QE (Nvidia GTX960M, I7 Skylake). However, it is not working well. Secure boot and Fast boot are not enabled.

I have tried all these steps with the "Prime select intel", nvidia drivers 361 and 364 options; and also trying with the 4.4-021 and the recent 4.6 kernels.

- I can make it work with "**ACPI=off**", not with "ACPI=ht". It works
  well, but it is not a secure mode, I think, as I have to use a lot of
  CPU power. Funny thing, the touchpad is not detected with this
  option, and the same happens with the Fn+Key combinations. External
  mouse is detected and works well.

  I can make it work with the "**nomodeset idle=nomwait**" option. It
  enters however in the login screen loop. With this option enabled,
  the touchpad is detected. If I use the nvidia driver 364, the refresh
  of the screen is very low, it "blinks" a lot. I also get the "wifi:
  unsupported splx structure" error at the beginning of the loading
  screen and continuous "pcieport... : receiver error".  does not help,
  also.

  If I use the "**nomodeset idle=nomwait ACPI=off**" I can go to the
  desktop menu... although it does not load, I just can see some icons
  while they blink among different positions in the screen.

Please, im desperate. What can I do? Can someone help me? I am really in a hurry! 15.10 does not work, either! Should I try with 14.04? I need to run some scripts asap :/

Thank you all.

Comment: What happens if you just use `nomodeset`?

Comment: Hmmm.. Same behaviour as with idle=nomwait.

Comment: Ok, if I start session with just nomodeset, with intel-microcode off and xorg on, it works, but very badly.

Aaaaaaand, I have just switched to nvidia 361, and started with std parameters, and it finally works. A week ago it didn't, it froze unless I used acpi=off or something similar. Finally :D

Comment: Congrats. For other readers: Start with nvidia-361 like user585097 did, since it comes with 16.04, and don't use ppa graphics drivers if you can avoid it. nomodeset + standard driver = winning combination in most cases.

Comment: I must say that in my case, same hardware, kubuntu 16.04, this does work. However, I can only have it working while using the nvidia card. If using prime (and nvidia-settings) I switch back to the intel graphics, I again need to do acpi=off and thereafter lose the touchpad. http://www.linlap.com/msi_pe60_prestige_pe60_6qe_gtx960m